# Choosing kernel size of cnn for time series data with multiple seasonalities

Tags: time-series, cnn, forecasting

I try to solve a standard time series forecasting problem using convolutional neural networks. The data has multiple seasonalities and so I wonder if a kernel size should reflect this fact e.g. for a 7-day seasonality one could use kernel size 7 in the first convolutional layer and so on but then what happens if there is both 7-day and 365-day seasonality? Questions:

1. Is my intuition correct? Maybe it doesn't really matter and I should just optimize kernel size using standard hyperparameter optimization techniques.
2. Is it better to just remove seasonalities using other techniques and only then apply CNN?
3. If my intuition is correct I suppose you could model these situation by concatenating outputs from multiple CNNs - one with kernel size 7 and another one with kernel size 365. Has such architecture been tried? Does it work?

Answers backed by papers are especially appreciated.